# Do flutter use single codebase for all different platforms?

Tags: flutter

Do flutter use single codebase to build web, ios , android and desktop apps .. ?
if yes !? How that been managed for different tech concepts? Is it draw a canvas and make a like apps ( drawn apps )  that resembles like actual apps ?

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/architectural-overview

Comment: I think this is answered by reading flutter documentation. it's not worth a stackoverflow question.

Comment: No one said yes or no , It is not obvious when googled .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes , but flutter draws a canvas for web that include all the magic .